# Node js - Combine two streams in parallel way

Tags: node.js, stream, promise

I need combine two streams in parallel way. I want to use these streams to write into two files some generated information. 
I have done the first stream (stream1). It looks like this:

```
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs');
var stream1 = fs.createWriteStream("random1.txt");
let ln = 1000000;
let j = 0;

function generateRandom()
{
    var reslt = true;
    do {
        ln--;
        j++;

        if (ln === 0) {
            stream1.write(...write randon number...);
            stream1.end();
        } else {
            reslt = stream1.write(...write randon number...);
        }
    } while (ln > 0 && reslt);
    if (ln > 0) {
        stream1.once('drain', generateRandom);
    }
}

stream1.on('error', (err) => {throw err;});

var stream1Promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    try {
        generateRandom();
        });
    } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
    }
});

stream1Promise
    .then(function(callback) {
        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback();
        }
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Error occurred: ", error);
        stream1.end();
    });
```

But I don't understand how to add another one stream stream2 so that it writes different random information to another file. 
I've tried to use process.nextTick in callback of stream1.write to switch my streams, but I get all time **"FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory"** error.
Could anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: *"I need combine two streams in parallel way. I want to use these streams to write into two files some generated information."* - Explain what you want to achieve, not what you want to do to achieve it.

Comment: I want to generate two big files.

Comment: Okay. Is "Write a function that generates one big file and then call it twice." not sufficient?

Comment: No, write a function that generate two big and different files and then call   this function once.

Comment: It does not make a lot of sense to write a function that generates *two* random files. If you want a single function for some reason, write a function that calls the other function two times.

Comment: As for the "parallel" part, node.js is single-threaded. Whether you write two files A and B like this AAAAABBBBB or like this ABABABABAB takes the same amount of time.

Comment: Should I use only one stream for writing a function that generates one big file and then call it twice?

Comment: As I see it, the function only needs a file name and the number of lines/bytes/whatever as arguments. Create a stream object as a local variable inside the function. Either write the function so that it takes a callback as its last argument, like node functions do, or that it returns a promise. Not both.

Comment: That promise doesn't make any sense to me. It resolves immediately, not when the stream is done writing. Is that what you wanted it do?

Comment: Please show us exactly how you "*tried to use process.nextTick in callback of stream1.write to switch my streams*" so that we can reproduce the error